# Iterating in nokogiri with rails doesn't work

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, nokogiri

So I wrote some nokogiri code that works in a test `.rb` file but when I put it inside a rails app model it won't iterate and just returns the first value. Here is the code that iterates correctly:

```
require "rubygems"
require "open-uri"
require "nokogiri"

url = "http://www.ebay.com/sch/Cars-Trucks-/6001/i.html?_from=R40&_sac=1&_vxp=mtr&_nkw=car+projects&_ipg=200&rt=nc"
data = Nokogiri::HTML(open(url))

data.css(".li").each do |item|
  item_link = item.at_css(".vip")[:href]
  item_doc = Nokogiri::HTML(open(item_link))

  puts item_doc.at_css("#itemTitle").text.sub! 'Details about', ''
end
```

Here is the same code in a rails app that only returns the first title it finds:

```
require "rubygems"
require "open-uri"
require "nokogiri"


class EbayScraper
  attr_accessor :url, :data

  def initialize(url)
    @url = url
  end

  def data
    @data ||= Nokogiri::HTML(open(@url))
  end

def titles
    data.css(".li").each do |item|
      item_link = item.at_css(".vip")[:href]
      item_data = Nokogiri::HTML(open(item_link))
      return item_data.at_css("#itemTitle").text.sub! 'Details about', ''
    end 
  end

ebay = EbayScraper.new("http://www.ebay.com/sch/Cars-Trucks-/6001/i.html?_from=R40&_sac=1&_vxp=mtr&_nkw=car+projects&_ipg=200&rt=nc")
titles = ebay.titles
puts titles
```

Why does the first code iterate through the whole thing and the second bunch of code just returns the first one?

Thanks for your time in advance!

Comment: You're returning from your `each`. Don't you want to `map` (or `collect` instead of returning during the first iteration? You're comparing code that behaves very differently during iteration.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. You're violating eBay's TOS, specifically `use any robot, spider, scraper, or other automated means to access our Services for any purpose;` and `bypass our robot exclusion headers, interfere with the working of our Services, or impose an unreasonable or disproportionately large load on our infrastructure;`. Instead use their [API](http://pages.ebay.com/help/sell/developers-program.html); That'll keep you happy because it'll keep them happy so they won't ban you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because you have a `return` statement in your loop that exits your `titles` function.